# Python: Create a file which contains a particular string and does not contain another particular string

Tags: python

I am trying to write a script that removes rows containing one string and keeps rows containing another. I think I have an indentation error at the end, can anyone see how to fix this?

```
import os
import sys

#Reading Input file
f = open(sys.argv[1]).readlines()

for line in f: #(read line 0 to last line of input file)
if 'Futures' in line and 'Elec' not in line: #if string "Futures" is not there in dictionary i.e it is unique so store it into a dictionary
#f = open("C://Python27//New_File.csv", 'w')
#f.close()
#opens and close new file
nf = open("C://Python27//New_File.csv", "w")
nf.write(data)
nf.close()
```

Comment: "I think I have an indentation error at the end" Yes, I agree. The error is that you have no indentation at all.

Comment: You have more than one, you will also completely overwrite each time opening with `w`

Answer (score 0):

Your indentation and logic are both wrong, if you keep opening with `w` you will end up with a single line, you need to open the output file once outside the loop and write as you go:

```
import sys

#Reading Input file
with open(sys.argv[1]) as f, open("C://Python27//New_File.csv", "w") as out:
    for line in f: #(read line 0 to last line of input file)
        if 'Futures' in line and 'Elec' not in line: #if string "Futures" is not there in dictionary i.e it is unique so store it into a dictionary
             out.write(line)
```

You can also iterate over the file object, there is no need or reason to use readlines unless you actually need a list of lines.

On another note, you may want to handle the cases where a file is passed that does not exist or you do not have permissions to read.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
for line in f: 
    if 'Futures' in line and 'Elec' not in line:
        nf = open("C://Python27//New_File.csv", "a")
        nf.write(data)
        nf.close()
```

Comment: Thanks to all for their contribution, just moving slightly on from that, is it possible to check if a certain value exists in one specified column?

Comment: you mean 1 character in 1 column ?

Comment: Hi Anthony, no I mean 1 string for example appearing in a specific column field, as opposed to checking the entire row.

Comment: If your csv values are separated by commas you can always count the commas and then apply your code